# Manage to access data and send from different components and handle them

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to create a `layer` where I can handle different actions from users.

From example, when you `click a div`, creates an `layer of type 1` and then sends it to the `layer component` to start showing a list of `dropdown` (for example).

As I'm new in react, I've did something, but it thrown me tons of errors and it doesn't seems to work.

This is what I've build: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-agnesi-47suvp

What I want is this:

- When you click a `.group-item` (from Header  component) save as an object the `ID` of the `player` which `.group-item you clicked` correspond (also the clientX and clientY of the `.group-item`) and then pass a function to display the `.dropdown` inside `layers component` which will also have the data you stored from the `Header component` (ID, clientX, clientY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed several mistakes:

- In some places you access `layer.type`, but you create a `layer` with property `layerType` instead; make sure to be consistent
- when you add a new layer, make sure to build an *array*:

```js
const addNewLayer = (object) => {
  listLayers((layerObject) => ([ // Note the square brackets, instead of curly braces
    ...layerObject, // Previous array of layers
    object // New layer to be added
  ]));
};
```

- In `Layers.js`, do not change a state directly at the root of your function component body: this creates an infinite rendering loop (the function re-runs whenever its state changes); in your case, you can wrap it in a `useEffect` that depends on `layers` prop:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  layers.forEach((l) => {
    if (l.layerType == 1) {
      console.log("layer type 1 found! .. set .dropdown to be seen");
      setLayerActive(true);
    }
  });
}, [layers]); // Re-run only if the list of layers changes
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-browser-iiip34

Comment: Thank you! I've also searched and find some tutorials about using context because it lets you access the data from different components